# Using a Dataframe to Display Column Data as an Individual Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I had a big dataset which I munged and cleansed to finally look like shown in the image. The clean dataset is given below.

```
RegistrationNo  StudentName   Date        ClassAttend
16SCSE101002    Eric Brown    12-03-2019    1
16SCSE101002    Eric Brown    08-03-2019    1
16SCSE101002    Eric Brown    12-03-2019    1
16SCSE101002    Eric Brown    15-03-2019    1
16SCSE101002    Eric Brown    08-03-2019    1
16SCSE101002    Eric Brown    22-03-2019    0
16SCSE101002    Eric Brown    22-03-2019    0
16SCSE101002    Eric Brown    26-03-2019    1 
16SCSE101005    Derek Oldman    15-02-2019  1
16SCSE101005    Derek Oldman    12-02-2019  0
16SCSE101005    Derek Oldman    15-02-2019  1
16SCSE101005    Derek Oldman    29-03-2019  1
16SCSE101005    Derek Oldman    12-02-2019  0
16SCSE101005    Derek Oldman    29-03-2019  1
16SCSE101005    Derek Oldman    02-04-2019  1
16SCSE101005    Derek Oldman    02-04-2019  1
16SCSE101005    Derek Oldman    12-03-2019  1
```

In the data, information is given of Students with  their respective Registration numbers, Names, Date of Classes and number of classes attended on that day.

I want to display each data in the column 'Date' as an individual Column.

The idea is to display the number of Classes attended by each Student on each Date. The student is identified by thier unique Registration numbers.

I want to view my dataframe with headers like below:

```
RegistrationNo | StudentName | Date1 | Date2 | Date3. .......  | DateN
```

followed by their individual datas provided under each of the above columns.

For Example: 
Sample Input:

```
16SCSE101002
12/3/2019

16SCSE101005
15/3/2019
```

Sample Output:

```
16SCSE101002
2

16SCSE101005
0
```

The user enters the Registration No. and they should be able to see the attendance of that student on each day of the classes conducted.

How can I go ahead with something like this?

Comment: Sorry, just added that.

Comment: It is better to include data in such a format that it is possible to for others to copy the data, i.e. no picture files. This way its easier for us to have a crack at the problem with our own computers.

Comment: Hope this helps. I can't seem to find a way to upload a csv here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear to me why you want to convert the dataframe to have date1, date2 etc. in the header. If the purpose is simply to get the registered students attendence on a given day I suggest two other options (there are probably hundreds of ways of doing this).

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
# Small subset of your data
df = pd.DataFrame({'RegistrationNo': ['16SCSE101002']*7,
                   'StudentName': ['DEREK TIMBER'] * 7,
                   'Date': ['12/03/2019', '08/03/2019', '12/03/2019', '15/03/2019', 
'08/03/2019','22/03/2019', '22/03/2019'],
                   'ClassAttend': [1,1,1,1,1,0,0]})
# Convert the 'string-dates' to pandas.datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Option 1, to get number of classes attended for a given registration number on a given date, use a simple filter and the `sum`-function

```
reg_no = '16SCSE101002'
reg_date = datetime(2019, 3, 12)

# This gives you what you want
df[(df['RegistrationNo'] == reg_no) & (df['Date']==reg_date)]['ClassAttend'].sum()
```

Or if you want the whole list with all the sums for each day do a `groupby`-`sum`

```
df_summed = df.groupby(['RegistrationNo', 'StudentName', 'Date'])['ClassAttend'].sum().reset_index()

  RegistrationNo   StudentName       Date  ClassAttend
0   16SCSE101002  DEREK TIMBER 2019-03-08            2
1   16SCSE101002  DEREK TIMBER 2019-03-12            2
2   16SCSE101002  DEREK TIMBER 2019-03-15            1
3   16SCSE101002  DEREK TIMBER 2019-03-22            0
```

And then you can use the previusly mentioned filter without the sum.

If you have very strong reasons for doing it the way you suggested please let me know (so I at least can delete this answer :)).

Comment: You nailed it. But I had to convert the df to show Date1 Date2... coz that is the procedure I am being forced to go by to complete this task. Please donot delete this answer. This helps!

Comment: To end this task, how can I save each output to a separate text file? Classattend 2 2 1 0 column in 4 different text files?

Answer (score 0):

You can play around a bit with the `pivot` function.

For example, you can try:

`df.pivot(index='RegistrationNo', columns='Date', values='ClassAttend')`

More examples [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html).

You should probably aggregate the number of classes attended by each student first (depends really on the exact thing you want to achieve - it's not really clear from your question and the screenshot of the data).

Comment: Registration Numbers will have duplicate entries, so I don't think we can index Registration column?

Comment: Yeah, that's why you should aggregate first - either sum up the attendance, so you can see the number of classes, or just do a max if you care whether the student showed up that day.

Comment: Ok the documentation example was great. I got what you pointed out with pivot.